# How to convert a character date time to be useable using dplyr and RPostgreSQL?

Tags: r, postgresql, datetime, dplyr, amazon-redshift

I have time stamp, column `Timelocal` in my data that's formatted as follows:

```
2015-08-24T00:02:03.000Z
```

Normally, I use the following line to convert this format to convert it to a date format I can use.

```
timestamp2 = "2015-08-24T00:02:03.000Z"
timestamp2_formatted = strptime(timestamp2,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC") 
    # also works for dataframes (my main use of it)
        df$TimeNew = strptime(df$TimeLocal,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
```

This works fine on my machine. The problem is, I'm now working with a much bigger dataframe. It's on a Redshift cluster and I am accessing it using the RPostgreSQL package. I'm using dplyr to manipulate data as the documentation online indicates that it plays nicely with RPostgreSQL.

It does seem to, except for converting the date format. I'd like to convert the character format to a time format. Timelocal it was read into Redshift as "varchar". Thus, R is interpreting it as a character field.

I've tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(lubridate)
```

**try 1 - using easy dplyr syntax**

```
mutate(elevate, timelocalnew = fast_strptime(timelocal, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"))
```

**try 2 - using dplyr syntax from another online reference code**

```
elevate %>% 
  mutate(timelocalnew = timelocal %>% fast_strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC") %>% as.character()) %>%
  filter(!is.na(timelocalnew))
```

**try 3 - using strptime instead of `fast_strptime`**

```
elevate %>% 
  mutate(timelocalnew = timelocal %>% strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC") %>% as.character()) %>%
  filter(!is.na(timelocalnew))
```

I am trying to adapt code from here: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/12/08/r-dplyr-mutate-with-strptime-incompatible-sizewrong-result-size/

My tries are erroring because:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: ...CAST(STRPTIME("timelocal", '%YSuccess2048568264T%H%M�����', 'UTC' AS "tz") A...
                                                             ^
)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create executeSELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT "timelocal", "timeutc", "zipcode", "otherdata", "country", CAST(STRPTIME("timelocal", '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S', 'UTC' AS "tz") AS TEXT) AS "timelocalnew"
FROM "data") AS "master"
2: Named arguments ignored for SQL STRPTIME
```

It would seem that strptime is incompatible with RPostgreSQL. Is this the right interpretation? If so, does this mean there is no means of handling date formats within R if the data is on Redshift? I checked the RPostgreSQL package documentation and did not see anything related to specifying time formats.

Would appreciate any advice on getting date time columns formatted correctly with dplyr and RpostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Traditional R functions will not work here.
Your should go with SQL translation which has been evolving in the latest versions of `dplyr` and `dbplyr`.
The following worked for me:

```
library(dbplyr)
mutate(date = to_date(timestamp2, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Note, I am using AWS Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
as.Date(strptime(timelocal,format = "%YYYY/%MM/%DD %H:%M:%OS"),tz="UTC")
```